# Command to get a file from s3 with the prefix and last updated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

How can I get a file from the s3 which has a new last modified date? and has certain words in the file name.

Comment: By "new last modified date", I presume you want to know when a file is uploaded to S3. You can use S3 event triggers and AWS Lambda to respond to files being uploaded. Note that files in S3 cannot be updated in place - instead, they are replaced. The event data that your Lambda function receives will include the S3 object's key so you use filter for specific words in the filename.

Comment: but the s3 bucket has the modified date so I am trying to get the file where the last modified date is newer.

Comment: What are you looking at when you refer to the S3 bucket last modified date?